# Measures to compare two spatial distributions in Python

Tags: python, geospatial, spatial, geopandas

I am working on a housing market related project. I have two datasets with nationwide US coverage that measure similar indicators. Both datasets have location attributes i.e lat, long coordinates

```
Dataset #1 is Web Traffic to listing sites
Dataset #2 is Address Searches
```

Both datasets are aggregated up to a defined geo, say, `US zipcode` in this case.

Here's what the dataset schema looks like:

```
Dataset #1:

zipName
zipCode
zipGeometry
traffic_count

Dataset #2: 

zipName
zipCode
zipGeometry
search_count
```

I'd like to compare the spatial distribution / spatial correlation between the two. How do I compare the coverage between the two? How do I identify coverage gaps the spatial distributions?